# run python script with and without output

Tags: python, linux, cron

I have h problem, i need to run a backup script with no output to the screen at all the problem is i need to do it only if its running from the crontab in linux.

So if a user open the script it will load the UI menu

But from the crontab i want to add an argument so it will run without any output, something like:

```
07 00 * * *     /root/idan/python nw_backup.py -s
```

s for silent :)

From my search here i found how to run only one command with subprocess module

Thanks !

Comment: Do you mean you want to alter your script to take command line arguments? In that case, look into [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sys.html#sys.argv) and [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just dump all output (stdout and stderr) to `/dev/null`.

```
/root/idan/python nw_backup.py -s > /dev/null 2>&1
```

`2>&1` basically means, dump stderr (`2`) same to where you dump stdout (`&1`).